# How to access to LinkedIn events via API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I found v1 documentation - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/events/events-api

But when I make request to events endpoint, I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
    <status>410</status>
    <timestamp>1582275439940</timestamp>
    <request-id>47DX3UY3N4</request-id>
    <error-code>0</error-code>
    <message>This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs</message>
</error>
```

I've tried to make request to v2 API and received: `Resource events does not exist`

So are there any way to access Linked in events via API?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I have just hit the same issue/story.